# Sistema de tickets en php y mysql

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

estoy trabajando en un sistema de tickets para una mesa de ayuda, necesito saber cuanto tiempo duro abierto un ticket hasta que se cerro, se que se puede hacer con diff, ejemplo $total = $fechainicio->$dif($fechafinal);

El problema es que los tickets solo se resuelven en horas laborales, de lunes a viernes de 09:00 am a 19:00 pm, ¿habría manera de realizar un contador que haga el conteo de tiempo entre estas horas y cuando sean pasadas las 19 pm este se detenga y vuelva a contar pasadas las 9 am del siguiente día en caso de que el ticket aun no sea cerrado?

```
while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$id=$r['id'];
$created_at=date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($r['created_at']));
$description=$r['description'];
$title=$r['title'];
$project_id=$r['project_id'];
$priority_id=$r['priority_id'];
$status_id=$r['status_id'];
$kind_id=$r['kind_id'];
$nme=$r['nme'];
$asigned_id=$r['asigned_id'];
$category_id=$r['category_id'];
//utima actualizacion del ticket
$updated_at=date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($r['updated_at']));



$fechain= new DateTime($created_at);
$fechaout= new DateTime($updated_at);
$tiempo= $fechain->diff($fechaout);





$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from project where id=$project_id");
if($c=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
$name_project=$c['name'];
}

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from priority where id=$priority_id");
if($c=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
$name_priority=$c['name'];
}

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from status where id=$status_id");
if($c=mysqli_fetch_array($sql) and $id<>3) {
$name_status=$c['name'];
}


?>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>" id="id<?php echo $id;?>">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $title;?>" id="title<?php echo $id;?>">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $description;?>" id="description<?php echo $id;?>">

<!-- me obtiene los datos -->
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $kind_id;?>" id="kind_id<?php echo $id;?>">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $project_id;?>" id="project_id<?php echo $id;?>">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $category_id;?>" id="category_id<?php echo $id;?>">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $priority_id;?>" id="priority_id<?php echo $id;?>">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $status_id;?>" id="status_id<?php echo $id;?>">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $nme;?>" id="Nombre<?php echo $id;?>">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $asigned_id;?>" id="Nombre<?php echo $id;?>">


<tr class="even pointer">
<td>CIASCTI<?php echo $id;?></td>
<td><?php echo $title;?></td>
<td><?php echo $name_project; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $name_priority; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $name_status;?></td>
<td><?php echo $nme;?></td>

<td><?php echo $created_at;?></td>
<td><?php echo $updated_at;?></td>
<td><?php echo $tiempo->format('%d-%m %H:%i:%s');?></td>
```

Comment: Sin entrar demasiado a fondo en el problema, quizá sea más simple dejar los tickets abiertos sin más y luego en el cálculo quitar las horas que no contabilicen. Digo esto porque me parece complicado estar modificando cada ticket según horas, días laborales, etc. Podrías tener por ejemplo un método al que le pases el ticket cuado éste sea cerrado, y dicho método le quite las horas / días no laborales al intervalo de tiempo. Creo que eso es menos costoso ¿no?

Comment: No seria mas conveniente considerar  validar que el ticket solo sea posible cerrarlo entre las 9 y las 19 horas que señalas, así te evitas realizar operaciones extras de proceso, Validar que no se pueda cerrar el ticket después de las 19 horas, y si lo hacen, se considere del siguiente día.  Aquí el detalle seria el conteo de las horas "efectivas" de trabajo o atención que comprende la jornada laboral.